# Different no. of training points than the one I am asking for

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest

Does anyone know, what could be the reason, I am getting different numbers of my training samples than the one I am asking in the code? Like in my example, for crop no.6, I am asking for 200 points, while as you can see on the right, I am only getting 11?!

[image]

```js
//                   ///////Landsat data/////
// Define a function that scales and masks Landsat 8 surface reflectance images.
function prepSrL8(image) {
  // Develop masks for unwanted pixels (fill, cloud, cloud shadow).
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var getFactorImg = function(factorNames) {
    var factorList = image.toDictionary().select(factorNames).values();
    return ee.Image.constant(factorList);
  };
  var scaleImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_MULT_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var offsetImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_ADD_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var scaled = image.select('SR_B.|ST_B10').multiply(scaleImg).add(offsetImg);

  // Replace original bands with scaled bands and apply masks.
  return image.addBands(scaled, null, true)
    .updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask);
}


// Make a cloud-free Landsat 8 surface reflectance composite.
var dates = [
// ee.DateRange('2020-04-01', '2020-04-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-04-16', '2020-05-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-01', '2020-05-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-16', '2020-06-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-01', '2020-06-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-16', '2020-07-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-01', '2020-07-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-16', '2020-08-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-01', '2020-08-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-16', '2020-09-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-01', '2020-09-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-16', '2020-10-01'),
//ee.DateRange('2020-10-01', '2020-10-16'),
  
]
//var bands = ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5',
            // 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']
             
var addNDVI = function(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5','SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDWI = function(img) {
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDWI')
  return img.addBands(ndwi)
}

// //EVI
var addEVI= function(image){
  var evi= image.expression(
              '2.5*(NIR-RED)/(NIR+6*RED-7.5*BLUE+10000)',{
              NIR:image.select('SR_B5'),
              RED:image.select('SR_B4'),
              BLUE:image.select('SR_B2'),
            }).float().rename('EVI')
  return image.addBands(evi)
}

var list = dates.map(function(range) {
  return ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
      .filterDate(ee.DateRange(range))
      .filter(ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.bounds(ROI),
    ee.Filter.bounds(ROI_Eth)
  ))
  //.filterBounds(ROI)
      .map(addNDVI)
      .map(addNDWI)
      .map(addEVI)
      .select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI','NDWI'])
      //.select(['NDVI','NDWI','EVI'])
      //.mean()
      .median()
      .rename(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5','SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI','NDWI'])
      //.rename(['NDVI','NDWI','EVI'])
});

/////create a stacked layer from the landsat image///
//***first prepare area to clip the stacked image on**//
var clipped = ROI.merge(ROI_Eth);

//**now create the stacked image**//
var stacked = ee.ImageCollection(list).toBands().clip(clipped);
Map.addLayer(stacked, {bands: ["3_NDVI", "5_NDVI", "8_NDVI"]}, 'Stacked', false)


// // //Generate 4000 random pt sample
var random1 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: rice,
  points: 10,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
});

var random2 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: maize,
  points: 10,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
});

var random3 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: cotton,
  points: 10,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
});

var random4 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: potato,
  points: 10,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
});

var random5 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: SCC1,
  points: 10,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
});

var random6 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: SCC2,
  points: 10,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
});

var random7 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: mixed_cps,
  points: 10,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
});

// Paint the reference data into an image so we can sample it.
var referenceData = ee.Image().byte().paint(rice, 0).paint(maize, 1).paint(cotton,2).paint(potato,3).paint(SCC1,4).paint(SCC2,5).paint(mixed_cps,6).rename("class")
//var combined= random1.merge(random2,random3,random4,random5,random6,random7);
// Place the collections in a new collection.

var combined = ee.FeatureCollection([random1,random2,random3,random4,random5,random6,random7]);

// Flatten the collection to create a new collection with all the features.
var flattened = combined.flatten();

// // // Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = stacked.addBands(referenceData).reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: flattened,
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 30,
  //crs: 'EPSG:32636',
  tileScale: 16,
});


//How balanced are the training data?
print(training.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), ["class"]));
//Map.addLayer(training,{},'training_sample');


// Filter out the null property values and try again.
var trainingNoNulls = training.filter(
  ee.Filter.notNull(stacked.bandNames().add("class"))
);
// var sample=trainingNoNulls.randomColumn();
// var split=0.7
// var training_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split));
// var validation_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split));


var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50)
  .train({
    features: trainingNoNulls,   //training_sample,
    //.randomColumn().filter("random < 0.7"),
    classProperty: 'class',
    inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),
    
  })



var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified')
Map.addLayer(classified,{
    // min: 0,
    // max: 6,
    // palette: []
  },
  'classification', true);

// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());
```

Here is also the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/a83fc3e746cdca4e96323ff1ae1ece6f

Answer (score 0):

The goal should be to use [`ee.Image.stratifiedSample`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-stratifiedsample). You'll need to convert your feature regions into an image (it looks like that is what your `referenceData`  variable is). Add the result as a band to the image you want to sample (e.g. `stacked.addBands(referenceData)`) and then call `ee.Image.stratifiedSample` on it. It'll give you a feature collection you can use as `training`.